# C++ Win32 sockets

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I have a working socket console server with multithreaded clients app. I've only created console or OpenGL apps. So a windows app is new.

I'm porting my stocket server code to a Win32 API app, and running into some trouble. The server runs, and the clients connect and communicate with each other correctly, but the server window freezes.

From my screenshot, you can see my server messages are being output to my text box. But on reaching the msg loop the app freezes.

I've updated my message loop from

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

to

```
boolean running = TRUE;

while (running) {
    if (PeekMessage(&sys.msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        if (sys.msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            running = FALSE;
            //exitCode = msg.wParam;
            break;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&sys.msg);
        DispatchMessage(&sys.msg);
    }

    try {
        pseucode_socket_checking();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        running = FALSE;
    }
}


pseucode_socket_checking() {
    SOCKET incoming = INVALID_SOCKET;
    incoming = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

    if (incoming == INVALID_SOCKET) return;

    ...

    // create thread for socket.
}
```

[image]

Comment: use asynchronous sockets api and `AcceptEx`

Comment: @RbMm would your preference be async or thread? My background has been PHP so taking awhile getting used to strict c again.

Comment: my choise of course asynchronous i/o. but for you this probably be hard

Answer (score 2):

`accept()` is a blocking function, it waits until a connection is made.
Suggestion: put your accept() loop in a thread.

Windows needs that the message loop is unblocked. When something stucks it (like accept()), the app will freeze. So, let the message loop free from anything blocking.

Comment: mmm that makes sense.. I was trying to avoid creating a thread for listening for connetions, since it's an app designed to listen for connetions.

Comment: have I missed a function to check if a connection is waiting, or is a thread the only / best way to perform this?

Comment: There is select() but you will have to call it in a loop. There is also WSAAsyncSelect which posts a message to your window when a connection is ready - in effect, it does the same like a thread, which is the simplest method. A suggestion: start looking how Windows work, it's way different than Unix.

Comment: `WSAAsyncSelect()` is the right way to go if you want to incorporate non-blocking socket operations directly in a UI. Otherwise, perform the operations in the background instead, using a separate thread, overlapped I/O, an I/O Completion Port, etc.

Comment: Thanks all, I went with putting all the socket code in threads for now. I may rewrite it as async at a later date after some more research.